# How to set a before_action to route method in Stealth bot framework?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying use `before_action's` callback in my [Stealth](https://github.com/hellostealth/stealth/) Bot, but isn't work. I don't know if this is a correct way to follow.

This is my code:

```
class BotController < Stealth::Controller

  helper :all
  before_action :print_this, only: :route


  def route
    if current_session.present?
      step_to session: current_session
    else
      step_to flow: 'hello', state: 'say_hello'
    end
  end

  def print_this
    puts "\n\n\n\n\n aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \n\n\n\n"
  end

end
```

Nothing happens, no error, no print message.

Whats could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

`before_action` works in another controllers, but not in `BotController`

**EDIT 2:**
This is a log with behavior:

**1)** Using `before_action :print_this, only: :route`

```
sidekiq_1   | 2018-09-12T17:13:10.544Z 1 TID-gt9nk8dzx Stealth::Services::HandleMessageJob JID-1b773e7908fcb72b7aa10a3d INFO: start
sidekiq_1   | [previous_session] User 160479129292600: setting to 
sidekiq_1   | [session] User 160479129292600: setting session to hello->say_hello
sidekiq_1   | [previous_session] User 160479129292600: setting to hello->say_hello
sidekiq_1   | [session] User 160479129292600: setting session to main->show_menu    
sidekiq_1   | 2018-09-12T17:13:11.738Z 1 TID-gt9nk8dzx Stealth::Services::HandleMessageJob JID-1b773e7908fcb72b7aa10a3d INFO: done: 1.194 sec
```

**2)** Using `before_action :print_this, only: :say_hello` (`say_hello` is a action of `HellosController < BotController` HERE WORKS

```
sidekiq_1   | 2018-09-12T17:18:24.751Z 1 TID-gte80drk9 Stealth::Services::HandleMessageJob JID-62e6901208770b68439ac083 INFO: start
sidekiq_1   | [previous_session] User 1604791292926176: setting to atendimento->say_meus_atendimentos
sidekiq_1   | [session] User 1604791292926176: setting session to hello->say_hello
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   |  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | 
sidekiq_1   | [previous_session] User 1604791292926176: setting to hello->say_hello
sidekiq_1   | [session] User 1604791292926176: setting session to main->show_menu
sidekiq_1   | 2018-09-12T17:18:25.524Z 1 TID-gte80drk9 Stealth::Services::HandleMessageJob JID-62e6901208770b68439ac083 INFO: done: 0.772 sec
```

Is this, not working in `BotController` only.

Comment: Where do you expect to see `puts` printing its message to? STDOUT? A log files? The next web page?

Comment: Hello @spickermann in STDOUT!

Comment: Can we get the part of the server log that says what request is made and which controller/action handled the request? We currently don't have much to go on.

Comment: @JohanWentholt yes of course, I'll edit post again. And show it for you. But this controller are simplified to make more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know the reason to this not work, [route](https://github.com/hellostealth/stealth/blob/master/lib/stealth/controller/controller.rb#L36) is not a action, is only a special method of `Stealth::Controller`, so callbacks will not called by `before_action` or another callback.